# How do dvaitins interpret this verse from Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: philosophy, bhagavad-gita, dvaita

In chapter 8.21, Krishna Paramatma says that eternal unmanifest abode as supreme abode of him and never mentions any separate place as his abode.

> Bhagavad Gita chapter 8, verse 21: That supreme abode is called unmanifested and infallible, and it is the supreme destination. When one goes there, he never comes back. That is My supreme abode.

As I understand, Krishna Paramatma describes supreme abode or supreme destination is unmanifested. But I know that Dvaitins believe the supreme destination is a manifest loka like Vaikuntha.

How do dvaitins interpret this passage?

Comment: What is the issue with Dvaita, Advaita in this verse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dvaita interprets that *unmanifest* abode does refer to either of following:

- Supreme Lord Himself
- Resplendent form of the Supreme Lord

According to [Madhvacharya's Bhashya](http://nageshsonde.com/Bhagavad_gita.pdf) on Bhagavadgita:

> [Sanskrit Bhashya](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=8&field_nsutra_value=21&scmad=1&choose=1): avyakto bhagavānyaṃ prāpya na nivartante itimāmupetya [8।15] ityasya parāmarśāt।avyaktaṃ paramaṃ viṣṇuṃ iti prayogācca gāruḍe। dhāma svarūpaṃ tejassvarūpaṃtejassvarūpaṃ ca gṛhaṃ prājñairdhāmeti gīyate ityabhidhānāt।
>
> [English Translation](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-8-21/): The avyakta the unmanifest and aksara the indestructible is the resplendent Supreme Lord, Krishna Himself, upon whom attaining there is no more returning to samsara the perpetual cycle of birth and death. The Garuda Purana states: **The avyakta is the Supreme Lord Himself.** It shows the use of the word dhama or abode as also denoting the **resplendent form of the Supreme Lord**. Showing that the resplendent Supreme Lord’s form and abode are both indicated such are the confidential meanings understood by those of spiritual wisdom.

Note: For supporting first interpretation, he cited 8.15<sup>th</sup> verse of Bhagavad Gita and Garuda Purana.